# Access 2007 – Unable to Get "AcrobatPDFMakerForOffice" to Work

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf-generation, adobe

I am trying to help a small company that is using an .mdb database in Access 2007. Their previous programmer left little documentation, unfortunately. The problem occurs when they call some routines that are intended to create a PDF file from an Access report. The routines were written by Stephen Lebans, and are supposed to be safe and stable. The Lebans routines are called by VBA code.

Here is some more info. The company has a small network with two workstations. On one workstation everything works fine; it is able to call the Lebans routines and create a PDF file. On the second workstation the code appears to execute but no PDF is created. Adobe Acrobat DC was installed recently on both PCs. The problem creating PDF files on PC#2 began after they installed Acrobat DC.

I will probably call Adobe tech support to get their help. But before that I hope someone can help with several questions I have.

Question 1 - In the VBA editor, in Tools -> References, I see that "AcrobatPDFMakerForOffice"
is checked. Please let me know if I should have checked some other reference instead.

Question 2 - The "AcrobatPDFMakerForOffice" in Tools - > References seems to refer to the following file: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\PDFMaker\Office\AcrobatPDFMakerForOffice.tlb" ,
which is a type library file. Does that seem OK? Or should it point to a "dll" or "exe"?

Question 3 - On PC#1, which is creating PDFs correctly, if I click the Office button inside Access, 
select Access Options, then select Add-Ins, I see "Acrobat PDFMaker Office COM Addin" under the heading "Active Application Add-Ins". And the file it refers to is:
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMOfficeAddin.dll".
On PC#2, however, there is nothing listed under "Active Application Add-Ins". So I attempted to add it.
I clicked "Go" next to "Manage COM Add-Ins" at the bottom of the screen; then clicked "Add..." in the 
"COM Add-Ins" window that appeared; then navigated to the file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMOfficeAddin.dll"; then click "Add". But nothing appeared under the heading "Active Application Add-Ins".

Any thoughts on how I can add "PDFMOfficeAddin.dll" to the Active Add-Ins list; or if I need to at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cross Posted Here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=295390

As pointed out in that post Access can create a PDF natively now. There is no need of the Lebans code.